# titlesec warnings

Tags: sectioning, koma-script, titlesec

I am trying to make my own style for chapter headings using `koma-script` and `titlesec`. The document compiles fine, but some errors are generated:

```
Package titlesec Error: Entered in horizontal mode \chapter{Um capítulo de teste}
Missing number, treated as zero \chapter{Um capítulo de teste}
Illegal unit of measure (pt inserted) \chapter{Um capítulo de teste}
```

A MWE follows below:

```
\documentclass{scrbook}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\usepackage{polyglossia}
\setmainlanguage{brazil}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\usepackage[dvipsnames]{xcolor}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{titlesec}


\titleformat{\chapter}[display]
{\titlerule[.8pt] \vspace{10pt} \bfseries \huge %
{\filleft \hrulefill \chaptertitlename % 
\marginpar{\mbox{\fontsize{60}{72}\selectfont\color{gray}\thechapter} } } } %
{}{\titlerule[5pt] %
\vspace{2pc}%
}{}

\begin{document}
\chapter{Um capítulo de teste}

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're using wrongly `\titleformat`:

```
\documentclass{scrbook}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\usepackage{polyglossia}
\setmainlanguage{brazil}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\usepackage[dvipsnames]{xcolor}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{titlesec}


\titleformat{\chapter}[display]
  {\titlerule[.8pt]\vspace{10pt}\bfseries\huge}% before code
  {\filleft \hrulefill\ \chaptertitlename %
   \smash{\makebox[0pt][l]{\hspace{1cm}\fontsize{60}{72}\selectfont\color{gray}\thechapter}}}% label format
  {1ex}% space before the title part
  {\titlerule[5pt]\vspace{2pc}}% format before the title
  {}% the title

\begin{document}
\chapter{Um capítulo de teste}

\end{document}
```

Don't use `\marginpar`, but rather a "smashed" box that so takes zero space, as in the shown code.

[image]

Comment: Great, it worked fine. I didn't know the `\smash` command, it's easier than using `\marginpar` in this case.